# Need to display a Jan 1st post as the site's front page on Jan 1st, and Jan 2nd post as front page on Jan 2nd etc

Tags: posts, custom-field, loop, query, date

slightly unusual client request. I'm using Divi and I have a nice Divi layout created for a video and text post which is ready to go. The client wants to create 365 posts (one for each day of the year and titled as such) based on this layout by just dropping in a video embed and text, and have the site essentially run with a different post display full width (ie just the post/header/footer) for each day of the year. ie - the Jan 1st post would become the site's front page on Jan 1st, and the Jan 2nd post become the front page on Jan 2nd.

The client wants to launch the site with 365 completed finished posts - all live. ie - 1st Jan, 2nd Jan ... 31st Dec. When the user goes on to the site he wants the post for 1st Jan to become the front page for 1st Jan etc and then 2nd Jan on 2nd Jan. ie - no republishing, scheduling or changing modified dates.

IT seems like there should be a simple solution, but I'm stumped. Does anyone have any great ideas? Much appreciated! (no url yet as it's still a concept on a dev platform)

Comment: If the client refuses to set the publish date, then you'll need to have them set the permalink very specifically. Trying to manually convert posts entitled "January 1" etc. would be awfully risky. If instead they use permalinks like "0101" (01 meaning January the first month, second 01 meaning the first day of that month) then you can rely on that to determine which post to display.

Comment: There are no date permalinks.

Comment: There will be a publish date, but the client doesn't want to reschedule or republish existing posts. Imagine 365 on this day, January 1st ... posts or a series of posts each of with a different set of birthdays on it - that's the kind of content. He wants it written up and then left to run so that the Jan 1st post/page displays AS the static front page on Jan 1st, and then at 12am Jan 2nd, the Jan 2nd post displays as the static front page.

Comment: I've looked at queries and hooks - for example this idea - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/324257/repost-post-on-specific-date-every-year - , but I cannot work out how to integrate them into a page template.

Comment: If you can't rely on published date or permalinks, all you're left with is post title. So, you'll need to create a `front-page.php` or similar template that shows header and footer, and in the middle, sandwich a query that searches for (current date, converted to human-readable form) as a post title. You'll need a fallback in case it can't find said post, and then a whole lot of testing, and you may need to strip whitespace so for example if the client sets the title to "January(space)(space)1" instead of "January(space)1" it still recognizes that date.

Comment: "If you can't rely on published date" Sorry if this wasn't clear - but I didn't say the published date cannot be relied on. The client just doesn't want to go down the route of republishing posts and cron jobs in case one glitch sends the 365 posts out of sync. Fully intend to set the Jan 1st post to published/modified on Jan 1st (probably 2018 so all the dates can be set as 'published')

Comment: I have tried a query and I can get the correct blog title to be displayed as body text (using the code on this thread: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53462/on-this-day-php-code ) but how do I get the query to output as a blog post via the Divi blog module?

Comment: That would be a question for the authors of Divi.